# Where to put Discord JS Bot Presence code?

Tags: discord.js

So I was trying to put code into my Discord bot to give it a custom status for users to see, then when I found the code I had no idea where to put it.
Here's the code: where should I put it?

```js
    * Sets the full presence of the client user.
   * @param {PresenceData} data Data for the presence
   * @returns {Promise<ClientUser>}
   * @example
   * // Set the client user's presence
   * client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'with discord.js' }, status: 'idle' })
   *   .then(console.log)
   *   .catch(console.error);
   */
  setPresence(data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let status = this.localPresence.status || this.presence.status;
      let game = this.localPresence.game;
      let afk = this.localPresence.afk || this.presence.afk;

      if (!game && this.presence.game) {
        game = {
          name: this.presence.game.name,
          type: this.presence.game.type,
          url: this.presence.game.url,
        };
      }
```

This code above belongs to the `ClientUser.js` file. It might belong to other files like `Presence.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it anywhere but most likely you want to put it into your `ready` event like

```js
    client.on('ready', () => {
        client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'with discord.js' }, status: 'idle' })
        console.log(`${client.user.username} is up and running!`);
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            name: ".help",
            type: "PLAYING"
        }
    });
});
```

The status can be `online`, `idle`, `dnd`, or `invisible`. (dnd is Do not disturb)

The other variable here is activity. It is a group of two variables: `name` and `type`.

The name is what the bot is doing. This is a string of your choice. The type is the other thing that will help it display as. It can be `"PLAYING"`, `"STREAMING"`, `"WATCHING"`, `"LISTENING"`, and `"CUSTOM_STATUS"`.